# Информация из двух связанных моделей ForeignKey на Django

Tags: python, django, foreign-key

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

from django.utils import timezone


class Worker(models.Model):
    name_worker = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name=u'Имя сотрудника')
    surname_worker = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name=u'Фамилия сотрудника')
    position_worker = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name=u'Должность сотрудника')
    #id_worker = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name=u'ID сотрудника')
    #visitorrr = models.ForeignKey('Visitor', related_name='workers', verbose_name=u'Информация о сотруднике:')

    verbose_name = "сотрудник"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_worker + '\n' + self.surname_worker + '\n' + self.position_worker


class Visitor(models.Model):
    name_visitor = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name=u'Имя посетителя')
    surname_visitor = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name=u'Фамилия посетителя')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name=u'Номер телефона')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=60, verbose_name=u'Адрес')
    id_worker_visitor = models.ForeignKey(Worker, verbose_name=u'Сотрудник', null = True)
    entry_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name=u'Время входа')
    time_out = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null = True, verbose_name=u'Время выхода')
    id_visitor_doc = models.ForeignKey(Documentation,verbose_name=u'Документ', null = True)
    statuss = models.ForeignKey(Statuses, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=u'Статус')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.name_visitor, self.surname_visitor)

    verbose_name = "посетитель"
```

Файл **views.py**

```
@login_required
def visitor_detail(request, pk):
    #visitor = get_object_or_404(Visitor, pk=pk)
    #worker = get_object_or_404(Worker, pk=pk)
    #Visitor.objects.get(pk=pk)
    #workers = visitor.workers.all()
    #workers = get_object_or_404(Visitor, pk=pk)
    #comments = task.comments.all()
    return render(request, 'bl/visitor_detail.html', {
    'visitor': Visitor.objects.get(pk=pk),
    'workers': Worker.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    })
    #return render(request, 'bl/visitor_detail.html', {'visitor': visitor, 'workers': workers})
```

**visitor_detail.html**

```
<div class="worker">
        {% for visitor in workers.visitor.all %}

        <h6>Сотрудник: <b>{{ visitor.id_worker_visitor}}</b></h6>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Подскажите, как мне вывести какой посетитель у какого сотрудника. Мне нужно вывести данные из двух таблиц. Я запуталась

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**view**:

```
@login_required
def visitor_detail(request, pk):
    visitor = get_object_or_404(Visitor, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'bl/visitor_detail.html', {
        'visitor': visitor,
    })
```

В шаблоне отобразим информацию о посетителе и о сотруднике, который его обслуживал, **visitor_detail.html**:

```
<div class="worker">
        <h6>Клиент: <b>{{ visitor.name_visitor }}</b></h6>

        <h6>Сотрудник: <b>{{ visitor.id_worker_visitor.name_worker }}</b></h6>
</div>
```

Дополнение к ответу:
Не совсем логично писать `id` в название fk, django сам подставляет в конце названия `_id`. Ну и оставим только имя связанной таблицы. Поправьте

```
id_worker_visitor = models.ForeignKey(Worker, verbose_name=u'Сотрудник', null = True)
```

На

```
worker = models.ForeignKey(Worker, verbose_name=u'Сотрудник', null = True)
```

И, [добавим имя](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) к связи, для удобства:

```
worker = models.ForeignKey(Worker, verbose_name=u'Сотрудник', null = True, related_name='worker_visitors')
```

Но, у вас в моделях небольшая проблема архитектуры. У вас у каждого сотрудника может быть несколько клиентов, но при этом у клиента может быть только один обслуживающий сотрудник. Для решения этой проблемы, можно использовать связь [многие-ко-многим](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField). Тогда, конечно изменится немного подход к выгрузке данных и вы сможете получить:

- всех сотрудников, обслуживающих одного клиента
- всех клиентов, обслуживаемых одним сотрудником

Ещё замечание, в название полей не обязательно добавлять название модели, к примеру `name_visitor` можно заменить на `name` и смысл останется тем-же.

Comment: У меня немного другое нужно получить. Т.е. при клике на имя посетителя, я должна перейти в следующее окно (visitor_detail), где будет отображаться вся информация непосредственно о посетителе, в том числе имя сотрудника, который обслуживает данного посетителя. Т.е. мне нужно выгрузить не посетителя, а имя сотрудника.
Помогите, пожалуйста, добиться этого... никак не могу сообразить..

Comment: Так это ещё проще. Выгружаете клиента `visitor = get_object_or_404(Visitor, pk=pk)`, а в шаблоне `{{ visitor.worker.name }}` это с учётом моих правок в названиях полей для моделей. В вашем оригинале это `{{ visitor.id_worker_visitor.name_worker }}`

Comment: Не получается. Я пробовала изменять условие for и остальное, не выводится имя сотрудника. Либо я что-то не так делаю

Comment: видимо вы что-то делаете не так. какую именно страницу вы хотите создать? страницу со списком клиентов, страницу со списком сотрудников, страницу одного сотрудника со списком его клиентов или страницу клиента с информацией об обслуживающим его сотрудником?

Comment: У меня страница со списком посетителей. Имя каждого отдельного посетителя - ссылка. Переходя по ней, у меня открывается информация о посетителе (имя, фамилия, адрес, телефон) и я еще хочу, чтобы была информация о сотруднике, который обслуживает этого посетителя. Т.е. в админке django я уже добавила эту информацию (в том числе и имя сотрудника). Но на домашнюю страницу у меня получилось вывести только информацию из таблицы Visitor. Из таблицы Worker (т.е. как раз имя сотрудника) не получается

Comment: `@login_required`

`def visitor_detail(request, pk):`
 `visitor = get_object_or_404(Visitor, pk=pk)`
 `return render(request, 'bl/visitor_detail.html', {'visitor': visitor })`

Здесь, вроде бы, все нормально. Значит что-то не так в самом выводе информации в visitor_detail

Comment: подправил ответ, посмотрите код view и шаблона

Comment: А я for не убирала =( Спасибо Вам огромное, всё получилось!